# Qt: How Can I build Qt under Microsoft Visual C .NET 2005

Tags: c, qt, visual-c++-2005

I need to build and use Qt within Microsoft visual C 2005 project. Is it possible to do that and how to?

Comment: Have you checked out QT's (now free) visual studio plugin?

Comment: @necrolis: the add-in doesn't provide precompiled libraries, you still need to compile them yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Open the Visual Studio Command promt from your start menu, then switch to your Qt directory:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2005 -debug-and-release
nmake
```

configure supports many more options, consult the docs.

nmake will take some time, in my case it was almost 2 hours. That's ok, considering the size of the Qt framework.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release , 4.7 now has precompiled binaries for VS2008. I suspect that VS2005 is unlikely now. My attempts at building a version for Visual Studio were fraught with build errors. You will need to exclude the web kit from the build.

Try `configure -no-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -no-opengl -platform win32-msvc2005

   -no-libtiff -no-dbus -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit`

Then nmake.

[Pre built VS2008 binaries](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008)